# Invalid Object Name, Temporary Table Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I´m trying to optimize some process in my application but I´m stuck with this problem. My application is working so the entity mapping is correct. Simplifying what I´m trying to do is this:

```
using (var offCtx = new CheckinOfflineEntities())
{
    using (var trans = offCtx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    {
         DateTime purgePivot = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
         count = offCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"select L.* into #NewLegs from InventoryLeg L where L.STDUTC >= {0}", purgePivot);
         long d = offCtx.Database.SqlQuery<long>("select count(*) from #NewLegs").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I´m selecting some data I want to delete from one table, storing it in a temporary table so that I can use this temporary table in other queries to exclude related data.

The problem is, when I try to use the temporary table I´m receiving the exception SqlException: "Invalid object name '#NewLegs'."

Thank you for your time.

Comment: temp tables are stored in tempdb. so you would need to connect to that first to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the query like this.

And count returns int, not long.

> COUNT always returns an int data type value. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
var query = string.Format("{0} {1}",
    @"select L.* into #NewLegs from InventoryLeg L where L.STDUTC >= @STDUTC",
    @"select count(*) from #NewLegs")
var d = offCtx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query, new SqlParameter("STDUTC", purgePivot))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Merging would work for this simple example but it won't work for what I really need. I will have to execute a lot of other queries using the temporary table and merging them all would create a huge mess in my code.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida, What do you really need? If you have another code please post it, otherwise it's just an unclear question and will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I realy don´t know why but removing the parameter and adding it in the query solved the problem.

The code below works fine:

```
using (var offCtx = new CheckinOfflineEntities())
{
    using (var trans = offCtx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    {
         DateTime purgePivot = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
         count = offCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"select L.* into #NewLegs from InventoryLeg L where L.STDUTC >= " + purgePivot.toString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
         long d = offCtx.Database.SqlQuery<long>("select count(*) from #NewLegs").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```